# How to use MOdiagram for d-orbital splitting?

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemistry, modiagram

I've been trying to use the package MOdiagram to simply draw the orbital diagram of one atom, but I have the problem that MOdiagram (as far as I know) only allows you to input s, p, d, and f orbitals, all of which have a set number of suborbitals (so just blank lines), but in d-orbital splitting I only need two lines on one level. Since I'm terrible with words, here's a picture below of what I basically want to do (the lines can be boxes, so don't worry about trying to make that fancy too):[image: First Simple Goal]

If it's possible to add labels (which I've seen in the documentation supposedly is), then the picture below would be even better!
[image]

In both of the pictures, as I said, the lines can be boxes (it doesn't make much of a difference for me). Also, I don't need the two levels to be perfectly centered one over another or so ridiculously close as I drew them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I'll try to answer any questions as quickly as possible!

Thank you!

P.S. Sorry for my messy handwriting!

EDIT:
I did further digging in the documentation and found this, which did what I wanted in my first picture (albeit it's very sketchy), but I still can't get labels underneath or to the sides.

```
\begin{MOdiagram}[style=square]
    \atom{left}{
        2p = {0; pair, up, up}
        }
        \AO(0cm){s}{1; up}
        \AO(0.7cm){s}{1; up}
\end{MOdiagram}
```